# iTunes Store operation failed. You must supply a CFBundleIdentifier for this request

Tags: bundle

i just signed up for this place, i have made app everything is working fine with app all the certificates and files are updated but when i try to upload to app store from xcode i keep getting this error. if anybody could help me to fix it it will be great thank you

iTunes Store operation failed.You must supply a CFBundleIdentifier for this request.

Comment: anybody willing to help out ? been stuck here for couple days now. please it be really appreciated

Comment: Did you figure it out, mate?

Answer (score 3):

Your info.plist application is wrong.
open your info.plist,"Bundle OS Type code" is null.I met the same problem,and add "APPL" to "Bundle OS Type code",that's OK.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your info.plist configuration is wrong.
open your info.plist,"Bundle OS Type code" is null.I met the same problem,and add "APPL" to "Bundle OS Type code",that's OK. See image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpoAW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Login in Apple Developer, go to Certificates*Profiles, delete all development and distribute signing certificates and provisioning profiles. Then in Xcode8 you select "Automatically manage signing", recreate signing certificates and provisioning profiles,archive and upload to appstore again.

Answer (score 0):

This one nearly put me mad. How I fixed it was creating a test project and doing an archive on it, and validate, which passed. I then copies all of the build setting from the test project to my project and thankfully everything worked. I know its along way off doing it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i have done and it did work for me

i did have to explicitly add the bundle identifier in the .plist file like this

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.AppIdentifier</string>
```

instead of

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

the reason might be that i do have multiple target in the project and i was uploading the app from the application loader

please note that in both cases i was able to archive successfully

env. 
Xcode 10.1 
High Sierra 10.13.6