# altool supply a CFBundleIdentifier for this request xcode9

Tags: ios, swift, gitlab-ci, cfbundleidentifier

I use gitlab-ci, altool to upload ipa, I can generate ipa and xcarchive, and when use xcode open xcarchive, can upload to appstore normally, but when use altool, this error happens：`You must supply a CFBundleIdentifier for this request`, code: `1191`, the APPL has set, can some one resolve this issue?? My xcode version is 9.4.1

the export shell is:

```sh
- xcodebuild clean archive -workspace $scheme.xcworkspace -scheme $scheme -configuration Release -archivePath build/$scheme | xcpretty
- xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "build/$scheme.xcarchive" -exportPath "build/$scheme.ipa" -exportOptionsPlist "ExportOptions.plist" | xcpretty
```

the upload shell:

```sh
altool="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Versions/A/Support/altool"
time "$altool" --validate-app -f "pathto.ipa" -u $user -p $password -t ios --output-format xml
echo "upload app ..."
time "$altool" --upload-app -f "pathto.ipa" -u $user -p $password -t ios --output-format xml
```

can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277355/itunes-store-operation-failed-you-must-supply-a-cfbundleidentifier-for-this-req/51020367#51020367), but can not resolve this issue.

I found in DistributionSummary.plist, the team name is null, and in Packaging.log, I found teamName=null:

```
distributionMethod(resolved)='', team(resolved)=''>
    Chain (11, self inclusive):
```

I tried manual and automatic sign, the result is the same, `teamName=null`.

Comment: Does your `Info.plist` contain the `CFBundleIdentifier` key and value?

Comment: yes，  
   
  

<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>